# Only verify subtree with XML Schema 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, libxml2, xsd-validation

I have a question regarding the validation of only a subtree of an XML document.
Consider the following input format:

```
<root>
  <configurationA>...</configurationA>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB>
  <configurationC>...</configurationC>
  <configurationD>...</configurationD>
</root>
```

The idea is to have multiple configurations in one large XML file. 
**Each component may only parse and validate its own configuration and should not need to know anything (not even the name of the tag).**

e.g. For component B it would be ideal to have an xsd file that looks like the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
        <xs:element name="configurationB" type="ConfigurationType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Unfortunately this does not work because of the ambiguity of the elements. 
I also tried to define occurence bounds for the `xs:sequence` or use `xs:choice` instead - In every case I get some error like this (from online validators).

> Cos-nonambig: ConfigurationB And WC[##any] (or Elements From Their Substitution Group) Violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During Validation Against This Schema, Ambiguity Would Be Created For Those Two Particles.

I have heard that there are solutions for XML Schema 1.1 but the project I am working on is currently using libxml2 in C++ which only supports Schema version 1.0.
**Changing the parser is currently not an option.**

Is there a solution that can be used to achieve this?

---

Additional examples to further describe what the XSD for component B should be able to match:

```
<root>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB> <!-- config for B available exactly once -->
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <configurationA>...</configurationA>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB> <!-- config for B available exactly once -->
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <configurationC>...</configurationC>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB> <!-- config for B available exactly once -->
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB> <!-- config for B available exactly once -->
  <configurationA>...</configurationA>
</root>
```

The following examples should fail:

```
<root>
  <!-- missing config for B -->
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <configurationA>...</configurationA>
  <!-- missing config for B -->
  <configurationC>...</configurationC>
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB>
  <configurationB>...</configurationB> <!-- duplicate config for B -->
</root>
```

Comment: I suspect you're looking for a tactical solution to an `xsd:any` problem where you instead ought to be reconsidering the overall design.  Start with whether disparate components really ought to be trying to validate a combined configuration file using a single, combined XSD.

Comment: @kjhughes Thank you for your answer. I was looking for a workaround for a not so uncommon problem (which was solved in XML Schema 1.1) but it looks like I'm out of luck. The new solution will be to use multiple configuration files - each with it's own xsd file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`xmlSchemaValidateOneElement`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaValidateOneElement). If this doesn't work, you can always move an element to its own document using the tree API.